# how to install libboost-all-dev in a python virtualenv? (without using sudo)

Tags: python, ubuntu, virtualenv, caffe, apt-get

I am trying to use faster rcnn on a remote server that I can not use "sudo" to install packages using "apt-get install". So my choice is to install a python virtual environment and install all packages in the virtual environment. However, I've found that without using "sudo" it is really hard to install packages and when I try to install faster-rcnn with caffe, I found that I do not have "libboost-all-dev" installed. What is the solution for this situation? Thank you so much! The operating system is Ubuntu 14.04.1.

Comment: `install a python virtual environment` without permission ? Need create a importer module for set all module.

Comment: It may be easier to figure out how to get `sudo` access.

Comment: Thanks. But the situation is, I cannot get sudo access... (this is the ultimate restriction I have, otherwise I would simply do "sudo apt-get install ..."

Answer (score 0):

try to download and install the package via [Ubuntu official link](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/libboost-all-dev).